# How to create a variable with (-) hyphen as one of the character in it in shell scripting

Tags: bash

I have a requirement of using a variable as abc-def which i am passing as a parameter and want to use in the shell script.

ex:

```
#!/bin/bash
abc-def="xyz"
echo "$abc-def"
```

there is an hyphen in the variable, i will have to use abc-def as a parameter and script needs to understand it wherever i will use.

Comment: `-` is not allowed in variable name.

Comment: how do you pass it as a parameter? You could name your variable differently internally

Comment: Where did the requirement come from?  Standard shells won't allow dashes in names; underscores are used instead.  Could you be misreading an underscore as a dash?

Answer (score 4):

You don't.

Variable names used by the utilities in the Shell and Utilities volume of IEEE Std 1003.1-2001 consist solely of upper and lowercase letters, digits, and the '_' (underscore) from the characters defined in Portable Character Set and do not begin with a digit. Other characters may be permitted by an implementation; applications shall tolerate the presence of such names.

Answer (score 1):

With a suitable recent bash, you can create an associative array, and use the "variable" name as an array key:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A vars
name="abc-def"
value=xyz
vars["$name"]=$value
echo "${vars["$name"]}"
```